# How do I get consistent rendering when scaling a JTextPane?

Tags: java, scaling, jtextpane, text-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Part 2 - How do I get consistent rendering when scaling a JTextPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566211/part-2-how-do-i-get-consistent-rendering-when-scaling-a-jtextpane)

I would like to allow users to zoom into or out of a non-editable JTextPane.

Running the example program below, I find that scaling the Graphics object results in inconsistent spacing between runs of bold text and non-bold text. If there is a single space between the bold and the non-bold, sometimes it is rendered too wide and at other zoom levels the space disappears and the adjacent characters overlap.

Without rendering hints, the spacing is correct at 100%, but incorrect at other zoom levels. With the KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS rendering hint, the results are consistent at all zoom levels, but the spacing between bold and non-bold is wrong even at 100%.

I tried this with both Java 1.6.0_13 and 1.6.0_23. The results were the same. Any suggestions how I can achieve attractive scaled rendering at all zoom levels?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class ScaledJTextPane extends JTextPane
{
    double scale_;

    public ScaledJTextPane()
    {
        scale_ = 1.0;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Try with and without the rendering hint
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        g2.scale(scale_, scale_);

        super.paintComponent(g2);
    }

    public void setScale(double scale)
    {
        scale_ = scale;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() 
    {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScaledJTextPane");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final ScaledJTextPane scaledTextPane = new ScaledJTextPane();
        StyledDocument doc = scaledTextPane.getStyledDocument();
        Style defaultStyle = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
        Style boldStyle = doc.addStyle("bold", defaultStyle);
        StyleConstants.setBold(boldStyle, true);

        scaledTextPane.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        String boldText = "Four score and seven years ago ";
        String plainText = "our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.";
        try 
        {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), boldText, boldStyle);
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), plainText, defaultStyle);
        } 
        catch (BadLocationException ble) 
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't insert text into text pane.");
        }

        final JComboBox zoomCombo=new JComboBox(new String[] {"75%",
                "100%", "150%", "175%", "200%"});
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel()
        {
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintChildren(g);
                scaledTextPane.paint(g);
            }
        };
       zoomCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              String s = (String) zoomCombo.getSelectedItem();
              s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
              double scale = new Double(s).doubleValue() / 100;
              scaledTextPane.setScale(scale);
              panel.invalidate();
              panel.repaint();
            }
          });
        zoomCombo.setSelectedItem("100%");

        // Add content to the window.
        scaledTextPane.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 300);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(zoomCombo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(900, 300);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```