# Scaling editable JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, editor, scale, custom-component

I want to scale the JTextPane for inline text editing. User can zoom/pan the text and double click on a JLabel to edit it. The editor should scale to the current zoom level.

I extended JTextPane and painted by scaling the component graphics. However editing does not work at scale different than 1.

How to scale a editable JTextPane?

Any solutions/pointers would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

I do not find the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566211/part-2-how-do-i-get-consistent-rendering-when-scaling-a-jtextpane) useful.

Following only scales the component and paints at different scale. However editing is not scaled.

```
public class ScaledJTextPane extends JTextPane {

      private double scale = 0;

      public ScaledJTextPane () {
        this.scale = 1;
      }

      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = null;        
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.scale(this.scale, this.scale);

        super.paintComponent(g2);
      }

      public double getScale() {
        return this.scale;
      }

      public boolean setScale(double xscale) {
        boolean status = true;        
        status = (xscale != 0.0 && xscale != Float.NaN);
        if (status) this.scale = xscale;

        return status;
      }      
    }
```

Comment: what did you found, please post here (edit your post) rellated code that shows what ..., please http://sscce.org/, may be trivial mistake

Comment: Problem I face is exactly the same mentioned in the [link] (http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.gui/2004-08/0449.html)

Comment: If you add
`public
    void repaint(
            int x,
            int y,
            int width,
            int height
    ) {
        super.repaint(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }`
It almost fix the problem, but I don't know how to fix double to int in the repaint.